# SAGA landform classification crashing on MAC, Windows, standalone or with QGIS

Tags: qgis, saga

I am trying to apply the "TPI-based landform classification" algorithm from SAGA. 
Originally in QGIS 2.14, on a MAC, then on windows and with SAGA standalone, but it quickly saturates memory/CPU and ends up crashing after a few minutes.

I have tried using a smaller elevation map, even with 10 x 10 pixels, as well as changing the projection of the data, but the issue remains the same.

Here is the log from QGIS:

Algorithm Tpi based landform classification starting...
io_gdal 0 -TRANSFORM 1 -INTERPOL 0 -GRIDS "/var/folders/c3/b7snydx51hl3ytjckcs6bq580000gn/T/processing698bae80d9d24acab1a1ba0e08e8edcd/f96bf62b13bb4c3183ece82e146a4dba/DTMAlvaresASTERSAGAproj.sgrd" -FILES "/Users/yannick/Documents/Alvares/Base dados/ASTER DTM/DTM_Alvares_ASTER_SAGAproj.tif"
ta_morphometry "TPI Based Landform Classification" -DEM "/var/folders/c3/b7snydx51hl3ytjckcs6bq580000gn/T/processing698bae80d9d24acab1a1ba0e08e8edcd/f96bf62b13bb4c3183ece82e146a4dba/DTMAlvaresASTERSAGAproj.sgrd" -RADIUS_A_MIN 0 -RADIUS_A_MAX 100 -RADIUS_B_MIN 0 -RADIUS_B_MAX 1000 -DW_WEIGHTING 0 -DW_IDW_POWER 1 -DW_IDW_OFFSET true -DW_BANDWIDTH 75 -LANDFORMS "/var/folders/c3/b7snydx51hl3ytjckcs6bq580000gn/T/processing698bae80d9d24acab1a1ba0e08e8edcd/1ed5f09736e4466a9521db2c1bee40fc/LANDFORMS.sdat"

---

## #####

---

SAGA Version: 2.2.3

---

library path: /Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/saga/
library name: libio_gdal
library : GDAL/OGR
tool : Import Raster
author : O.Conrad (c) 2007 (A.Ringeler)

---

Parameters
Grids: No objects
Files: "/Users/yannick/Documents/Alvares/Base dados/ASTER DTM/DTM_Alvares_ASTER_SAGAproj.tif"
Transformation: yes
Interpolation: Nearest Neighbor

loading: /Users/yannick/Documents/Alvares/Base dados/ASTER DTM/DTM_Alvares_ASTER_SAGAproj.tif

Driver: GTiff
Bands: 1
Rows: 470
Columns: 484

Transformation:
x' = -8.161063 + x * 0.000278 + y * 0.000000
y' = 40.094790 + x * 0.000000 + y * -0.000278

loading band [1/1]

/Users/yannick/.qgis2//processing/saga_batch_job.sh: line 4: 37503 Killed: 9 saga_cmd ta_morphometry "TPI Based Landform Classification" -DEM "/var/folders/c3/b7snydx51hl3ytjckcs6bq580000gn/T/processing698bae80d9d24acab1a1ba0e08e8edcd/f96bf62b13bb4c3183ece82e146a4dba/DTMAlvaresASTERSAGAproj.sgrd" -RADIUS_A_MIN 0 -RADIUS_A_MAX 100 -RADIUS_B_MIN 0 -RADIUS_B_MAX 1000 -DW_WEIGHTING 0 -DW_IDW_POWER 1 -DW_IDW_OFFSET true -DW_BANDWIDTH 75 -LANDFORMS "/var/folders/c3/b7snydx51hl3ytjckcs6bq580000gn/T/processing698bae80d9d24acab1a1ba0e08e8edcd/1ed5f09736e4466a9521db2c1bee40fc/LANDFORMS.sdat"
Converting outputs
Loading resulting layers

The following layers were not correctly generated.
Landforms
You can check the log messages to find more information about the execution of the algorithm

Comment: I am probably wrong, but looking at `ASTERSAGAproj.sgrd` in your filename, can I understand that it's ASTER data? If yes, is your data projected? (Map unit is in meters? or in degrees?)  I am wondering if the `-RADIUS` (100 and 1000) is the culprit, because SAGA uses map unit.  Thanks!

Comment: "Probably wrong"... but certainly 100% right !! Thanks a lot, I had tried different projections, but none of them had meter units. That was the trick !

Answer (score 1):

As identified by the comment from @Kazuhito, the solution was to reproject the data into a projection with meter units.